# Android 4.4.2 webview + targetSdkVersion=19 issues

Tags: android, webview

I'm working on an update for an app (implementing immersive mode) but I'm having issues with the webview as soon as I change the targetSdkVersion in the androidmanifest file.

At first it only rendered the background color. It did load the resources because I could see that happening in the debug console but it just didn't show anything. So I googled a bit and found an answer that stated I should disable hardware accelaration like this:

```
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Now it does show content but really tiny, as if the webview was zoomed out to 25% or something like that. Also it shows some sort of grid..?

I've attached two screenshots (taken with my phone which is actually too small for the layout but I didn't have my tablet around). The first is with `targetSdkVersion=18` (and looks like it should), the second is `targetSdkVersion=19` and is broken.

help?

[image: As it should be, targetSdkVersion=18]

[image: As it looks with targetSdkVersion=19]

Thanks,

Comment: According to the API notes for Android 4.4 https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html setting targetSdkVersion to 19 is the trigger to use the new Chromium engine rather than the legacy WebKit. Perhaps the engines interpret your HTML differently? At a guess I would start with the viewport meta tag.